# Change PHP filter to return submitted value rather than the field name using Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am using the below code in Gravity Forms for WordPress (functions.php). How can I change the below code so it will return the Field Value? It currently returns the Field Label.

The gform_merge_tag_filter can be used to add a custom modifier for this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_merge_tag_filter', function ( $value, $merge_tag, $modifier, $field, $raw_value, $format ) {
    if ( $field->type == 'checkbox' && $modifier == 'pipes' ) {
       $value =str_replace(', ', '|', $value);
    }
  
    return $value;
 }, 10, 6 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The value that was submitted in the field gets passed as the `$raw_value` argument, so you just need to return it instead of `$value`.

So to change your function to use `$raw_value` instead of `$value` in every instance would look like this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_merge_tag_filter', function ( $value, $merge_tag, $modifier, $field, $raw_value, $format ) {
    if ( $field->type == 'checkbox' && $modifier == 'pipes' ) {
       $raw_value=str_replace(', ', '|', $raw_value);
    }
    return $raw_value;
 }, 10, 6 );
```